# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginForm' available as request attribute

Tags: spring-mvc

Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginForm' available as request attribute. My login.jsp is as below.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/loginPage" commandName = "loginForm">
```

```
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="name">Username</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><form:label path="age">Password</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and my controller is

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/loginPage",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result,
            Map model)
```

can anyone suggest how can i resolve this exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "loginForm" key to ModelMap before you start using it..
Example:

```
//This code needs to be invoked first
     @RequestMapping(value="/onPageLoadOfLogin",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String onLoadOfLoginPage(ModelMap m){
    m.put("loginForm",new LoginForm());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
model.put("loginForm",new LoginForm());
```

This means that, your command name should be exactly the same as the `modelAttribute` name... so if your `commandName` in your `jsp` file is `"loginForm"` then you model should add the attribute with the name `"loginForm"`.

Please add model map attribute before rendering to login page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/loginPage" modelAttribute = "loginForm">
```

try adding modelAttribute in

also u need to first bind the form with the controller. To do this you can first perform a GET to perform the binding.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loginPage",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result,
        Map model)
```

after this do POST. And submit button will do the binding of its own in POST method calling. Your form will be like

```
 <form:form modelAttribute = "loginForm">
```